# The type initializer for System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions threw an exception

Tags: vb.net, box, blueprism

```
Dim stream As FileStream = New FileStream("jsonFile.json", FileMode.Open)
Dim iconfig As IBoxConfig = BoxConfig.CreateFromJsonFile(stream)

Dim admintoken As String = boxJWT.AdminToken()
Dim adminClient As BoxClient = boxJWT.AdminClient(admintoken)

Dim boxJWT As BoxJWTAuth = New BoxJWTAuth(iconfig)
Dim userToken As String = boxJWT.UserToken(userId)
Dim userClient As BoxClient = boxJWT.UserClient(userToken, userId)
```

The code is succed in Visual Studio,but failed at Blue Prism.
The error is occur at here --Dim admintoken As String = boxJWT.AdminToken()

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error message? Do you properly declare your external references in the Business Object Properties -> Code Options box?

Comment: yes ,I did it .and i try remove that .dll file , it will throw another exception.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue on mine by **deleting** the reference for "**System.IdentityModel**" and only having a reference to "**System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt**". It seems like there is a conflict in versions that causes this issue.